# Regression specification

Tags: regression

Hello statistic friends,

do I make any econometric mistakes if I regress:

$D/A = a + b_1 * A + b_2 * X/A + b_3 * Z + U$

D = Debt, A= Assets, X = Cash Flows, Z = Controls, U = error terms

I am a little bit confused since I have A in the denominator for my dependent variable and for one independent variable (but not in my controls). Simultaneously I use A as another independent variable.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to adopt OLS method for estimating the parameters of your regression model, you need to observe its [assumptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Assumptions). Regarding your problem, you might be concerned about a supposed perfect multicollinearity among the variables. However, only the fact of having "A" dividing another DV or being a DV itself does not imply multicollinearity.

Still, you should test how strong is the dependence between your DV in order avoid degraded estimated parameters due to ill conditioned data matrix. Take a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/89182/31536 to see a procedure to test this in R.